# Simulate data with directions with equal variance and apply PCA

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, pca, simulation

I would like to simulate $N$ observations for the single feature $X$ starting from a simple linear factor model of the form $X=A*P$ where $P$ is the factor matrix of the $K$ factors. Then, I would apply Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to the matrix of observations $X$ to recover those factors. I would like to restrict the factors in a way that they all have the same variance (for didactical purposes). How could I do that? And more importantly, what would be the result from the PCA method, given that there would be no ordering of the components as they have all equal variance? I wonder what a software like Python or R would give as a result and how I could interpret this.